# Creating a constant for a record that has an array within a case variant

Tags: arrays, constants, record, variant

I'm trying to create a constant for the following record:

```
type
  point = packed record
    case aSInt of
      0: (x, y, z: aFloat);
      1: (v: array [0 .. 2] of aFloat); { vertex }
  end;
```

I can declare a constant to set the first three variables like so:

```
const
  ZeroPt: Point = (x: 0.0; y: 0.0; z: 0.0);
```

However, when I try to include the array:

```
const
  ZeroPt: Point = (x: 0.0; y: 0.0; z: 0.0; v:(0.0, 0.0, 0.0));
```

I get a compiler error: 'Order of fields in record constant differ from declaration.

I can't figure out the proper syntax for the field order. Any insight to the proper format would be greatly appreciated.

Thank You,

MFM

Answer (score 0):

Here's a response I received from a friend of mine.

Since the x, y, z fields and the 'vector' v field share the same memory, you can't set different values for them independently. Changes to x, y, z will be reflected in v[0], v[1], and v[2]. Similarly, setting v[0], v[1], v[2] will affect x, y, z respectively.

In this record, the vector field is used when you want to pass/set a point as an array instead of setting x, y, and Z independently. Setting coordinates from an array can also be faster and allow the use of code that is more succinct.

This is an example of a variant record (the equivalent of a union in C). The purpose of this structure is to save memory by using the same memory region for storing different objects at different times. Although it can save memory, it makes it very prone to errors that are hard to detect. It makes sense to use it on embedded devices where you have severe memory limits (like few KB or few MB). On desktop applications unions/variant records are better avoided.

However, in the case of this point record, it is quite safe as the memory aligns perfectly for individual coordinates x, y, z and the v array.

So you only need to initialize one or the other.

```
const
  ZeroPt: Point = (x: 0.0; y: 0.0; z: 0.0);
```

or

```
const
  ZeroPt: Point = (v:(0.0, 0.0, 0.0));
```